# sum times dt within time ranges

Tags: r, sum, plyr

I would like to sum a column of time differences `diff` for 14 different users when these time differences occurred in some fixed time events.
here the head of the first dataframe with times differences 'diff`, this dataframe contains 152171 rows:

> head(hope)
>                times        users signal log `diff`
>   1 2014-01-13 00:00:16 00250902DC7D   true  ON   31
>   2 2014-01-13 00:00:47 00250902DC7D   true  ON   31
>   3 2014-01-13 00:01:18 00250902DC7D   true  ON   30
>   4 2014-01-13 00:01:48 00250902DC7D   true  ON   31
>   5 2014-01-13 00:02:19 00250902DC7D   true  ON   31
>   6 2014-01-13 00:02:50 00250902DC7D   true  ON   31

The second dataframe with 108 different times ranges (nrow=108)is:

> ```
>           start                 end
> ```
>
> 1 2014-01-14 06:30:00 2014-01-14 07:00:00
>   2 2014-01-14 10:30:00 2014-01-14 11:00:00
>   3 2014-01-14 18:00:00 2014-01-14 18:30:00
>   4 2014-01-14 22:30:00 2014-01-14 22:59:00
>   5 2014-01-15 02:30:00 2014-01-15 02:59:00
>   6 2014-01-15 09:00:00 2014-01-15 09:30:00

If I select the event manually (I chose by chance the 12th event..), it works...but I have 108 different evevnts...
`hope1 <- hope[hope$mode=="ON" & hope$times>events[12,1] & hope$times<events[12,2],]`
`ddply(hope1,.(users),summarize,sum=sum(diff))`

```
         users  sum
1 00250902DC7D 1857
2 00250902FA92 1857
3 00250902FB05 1857
4 002509030C41 1857
5 002509030E53 1857
```

****ok perfect, BUT ONLY FOR ONE EVENT****

**If I want to do it for 108 different events, should I use a loop maybe?**

Could you help me please?
Is anyone alive?

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be a starting point for you.

```
head(hope)
hope <- read.table(text="times users signal log diff
1 2014-01-13 00:00:16 00250902DC7D true ON 31
2 2014-01-13 00:00:47 00250902DC7D true ON 31
3 2014-01-13 00:01:18 00250902DC7D true ON 30
4 2014-01-13 00:01:48 00250902DC7D true ON 31
5 2014-01-13 00:02:19 00250902DC7D true ON 31
6 2014-01-13 00:02:50 00250902DC7D true ON 31", sep="", header=F,skip=1)

head(hope)
hope$V1 <- NULL
names(hope) <- c("date","time", "users","signal","log","diff")

hope$datetime <- as.POSIXct(strptime(as.character(paste(hope$date,hope$time)),
                          format="%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"))
hope <- hope[,c(7,3,4,5,6)]

hope
library(plyr)

# Define dates where you want to find the sum
# I chose different dates that the date you gave because I didn't have enough data to test
hope1 <- subset(hope, (datetime  >as.POSIXct(c("2014-01-13 00:01:18")) & 
                                  datetime <as.POSIXct("2014-01-13 00:02:50")))
# Find the sum
sum(hope1$diff)

# Find the sum by users 
ddply(hope1,.(users),summarize,sum=sum(diff))
```

I hope this helps.